# windows phone 8 MDM server setup

Tags: windows-phone-8, mdm

I am trying to setup an enrollment server for managing Windows Phone devices. I know that there is a discovery service at http://enterpriseenrollment.mydomain.com/EnrollmentServer/Discovery.svc which will provide the enrollment service URL.

1. What is the behavior of Discovery.svc?
2. Is this a service that I need to develop?
3. If yes, what sort of methods should be in there in this service?
4. How to setup the Enrollment service? What are its methods?

Answer (score 0):

Search for "Enterprise Device Management Protocol for Windows Phone" documentation. It is explained there:
[Enterprise Device Management Protocol for Windows Phone](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=enterprise%20device%20management%20protocol%20for%20windows%20phone&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CEEQFjAA&url=http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/C/4/5C460CE2-3B0F-45CE-805D-1A3D5697639C/WP8_Enterprise_Device_Management_Protocol.pdf&ei=IjP1UOv1KKya1AWq7YHYCA&usg=AFQjCNE7fEvr5RxwEYJWxPA-PqNsKZ5r4A&bvm=bv.41018144,d.d2k)

Comment: I have already referred to the documentation, and have created an empty Discovery.svc service. I get the response for the GET request correctly and the Company Apps UI attempts for a POST (as per the documentation), but then I get a 404 error message (I used fiddler to trace the request). On the UI, I get a message "Make sure that you have a Cellular data or Wi-Fi connection then try again....." - the same error message mentioned above.

From the document, the response for POST should contain the URL for the enrollment service - where should I configure this URL in the Discovery service?

Comment: @Riho where is this in windows forum? I am interested in the discussion.

Comment: @Riho : Can you please give the specific url which you answered.