# Will Windows Phone 8 supports MDM?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

1. How to start MDM server set up for Windows Phone 8?
2. Is there is api to install enterprise (not in store) app in wp8?
3. We have to get certificate policy and enroll credentials for DM client Server?
4. Is there is APIs for Remote Lock, Wipe and set password?

Thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14331365/windows-phone-8-mdm-server-setup

Comment: @PreetSangha Do you have any idea of questions 2 & 4?